# How I get data from cross domain query through ajax tool in salesforce?

Tags: javascript, ajax, salesforce

I wanted get data from cross domain data in salesforce. I follow on this article http://www.saaspie.com/cross-domain-ajax-requests-javascript/.  And one thing I'm not sure whether I need to make a setting for Proxy server in salesforce or no need. If it needs to make setting how could I do? I  make the simple code, it doesn't work. Did you have same problem?

```
    <apex:page >

          <script src="../../soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

          <script>
          sforce.connection.remoteFunction(
          {
          url: "https://www.brightscope.com/",

          onSuccess: function(response){alert("dfbgxdfbv");}
          }
          )
          </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: if brightscope.com don't allow **CORS** then your only choice is to proxy requests through your own server

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you for response. If you mean to do own server in salesforce, how could I do this?